# php datetime diff completely off

Tags: php, datetime, diff

So i have this very simple code but it refuse to work, and i have no idea why?

```
$date1= new DateTime (gmdate('H:i Y-m-d'));
$date2 = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo $date1->format('H:i Y-m-d') .'<br>'; returns //08:32 2018-06-08
echo $date2->format('H:i Y-m-d') .'<br><br>'; returns //04:32 2018-06-08

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);


$diffTime = $diff->format('%R%H:%I');

echo $diffTime; returns //+02:00
```

I'm no mathematician but i'm pretty sure the difference between 04:32 and 08:32 isn't 2 hours, but more like 4.

And if i change it it sometimes end up being even more off.

```
    $date1 = new DateTime ('now', new DateTimeZone('Indian/Comoro'));
    $date2 = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

    echo $date1->format('H:i Y-m-d') .'<br>'; returns //11:44 2018-06-08
    echo $date2->format('H:i Y-m-d') .'<br><br>'; returns //04:44 2018-06-08


    $diff = $date1->diff($date2);


    $diffTime = $diff->format('%R%H:%I');

    echo $diffTime; returns //+00:00
```

I just don't even.

Comment: It's working correctly at my end :) first snippet gives output of  "-04:59"

Comment: Why are you expecting 4 as the answer on the first? Now here and over there is still now. The timezone difference is another thing.

Comment: i'm expecting a 4 hours, because it's two different times.

Comment: No it's not two different times. If I call you now, you won't recieve the call four hours from now.

Comment: No, i understand that now [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50756863/9912983)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code. It returns **-07:00**

```
$date1 = new DateTime ('now', new DateTimeZone('Indian/Comoro'));
    $date2 = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

    echo $date1->format('h:i Y-m-d') .'<br>';/// returns //11:44 2018-06-08
    echo $date2->format('h:i Y-m-d') .'<br><br>';// returns //04:44 2018-06-08
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($date1->format('h:i Y-m-d'));
    $datetime2 = new DateTime( $date2->format('h:i Y-m-d'));

    $diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);


    $diffTime = $diff->format('%R%H:%I');

    echo $diffTime; returns //-07:00
```

Comment: My god, you're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

When you request for "now" date object, it returns you the present date. How it formats depends on your client locale, or the one you explicitly specify.

However, when you have two date objects, both on *now* (maybe formatted as two different timezones), when you do a compare (or diff), they are supposed to return the same value as inherently a date object is the number of ticks since 1/1/1970.

If you want to check, output the "ticks" property of each date, you will see they come out same.

Hence your code is working fine absolutely.

Comment: Uh, i didn't know that, you learn something everyday i guess.

Answer (score 0):

gmdate shows time without DST, and in New York it's currently DST.

If you use "Europe/London" instead you have DST on both ends.

```
$date1= new DateTime ('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$date2 = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo $date1->format('H:i Y-m-d') .'<br>';  
echo $date2->format('H:i Y-m-d') .'<br><br>'; 

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);


$diffTime = $diff->format('%R%H:%I');

echo $diffTime;  //+00:00
```

https://3v4l.org/b6Gkq

Comment: I'm sorry but when i do that, not only is the time of London off, but it still says +00:00 in the end.